# UWP Sockets Unable to Connect Over LAN

Tags: sockets, uwp

I am having some issues with sockets in UWP.

I'm trying to test some simple socket communications (stripped down version of the [MSDN example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/sockets)) between a mobile and a desktop on the same LAN subnet. I am developing in a VM (on a separate desktop) and can deploy to the VM and mobile. In that case connections work fine.

When I create an app package and install it on the desktop, I cannot connect.

I have windows firewall on the desktop completely off. The VM is set to have a separate IP on the network. I have checked all IPs I'm using are correct.

I am getting the typical: *A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time*

This is driving me crazy, if anyone has any helpful advice that would be much appreciated!

**edit: To clarify the above.**

My app has both both client and server roles (can connect to a listener, and is also listening itself).

App (on Mobile) --> App (on VM, deployed from VS) - this works fine, Mobile can connect to VM no problem.

App (on Mobile) --> App (on Desktop, installed from appx) - Mobile unable to connect to Desktop. Firewall on desktop disabled. Task Manager shows .exe listening on the correct port.

Thanks, Inci

Comment: Did you mean you install the server side on the desktop and client side on the VM and they cannot communicate?  Can you ping your VM successfully from the desktop and ping your desktop successfully from VM?

Comment: Thanks Sunteen, I have tried to explain better - see edit above.

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution to this - it appears connections over LAN need to have the Internet(Client & Server) capability selected.

I am most certainly connecting over my local network (specifically 192.168.0.15 (mobile) to .21 (desktop). It seems that when deploying with VS the app **doesn't** need the Internet capability.

If there is a more 'correct' solution I'll amend this.